# Como creo un CURSOR ADAPTER para mostrar datos de sqlite?

Tags: android-studio, sqlite

Hola tengo hecho tanto el metodo de insertar datos en la base de datos y leerlos pero lo que quiero es mostrarlos en un listview y estado leyendo que hay que hacerlo con un cursor adapter y no tengo muchos conocimientos sobre este, mi duda es como creo el cursor y lo llamo desde el main para mostarlo en un listview, este es mi codigo:

```
    public class SQLiteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        private static final String NAME = "Alumnos.db";
        private static final int VERSION = 1;

        public SQLiteHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, NAME, null, VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + AlumnosColumnas.TABLE_NAME + " ( "
            + AlumnosColumnas.DNI + " TEXT PRIMARY KEY,"
            + AlumnosColumnas.NOMBRE + " TEXT NOT NULL,"
            + AlumnosColumnas.APELLIDOS + " TEXT NOT NULL,"
                    + AlumnosColumnas.EDAD + " INTEGER NOT NULL)");
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE " + AlumnosColumnas.TABLE_NAME);
            db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + AlumnosColumnas.TABLE_NAME + " ( "
                    + AlumnosColumnas.DNI + " TEXT PRIMARY KEY,"
                    + AlumnosColumnas.NOMBRE + " TEXT NOT NULL,"
                    + AlumnosColumnas.APELLIDOS + " TEXT NOT NULL,"
                    + AlumnosColumnas.EDAD + " INTEGER NOT NULL)");

            if (oldVersion == 1) {
                //ALTER TABLE ADD ID
            } else if (oldVersion == 2) {
                //DROP COLUMN ID
            }
        }

        public long añadirAlumno (Alumno a) {
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(AlumnosColumnas.DNI, a.getDni());
            values.put(AlumnosColumnas.NOMBRE, a.getNombre());
            values.put(AlumnosColumnas.APELLIDOS, a.getApellidos());
            values.put(AlumnosColumnas.EDAD, a.getEdad());

            SQLiteDatabase sql = getWritableDatabase();

            return sql.insert(AlumnosColumnas.TABLE_NAME, null, values);
        }

        public Cursor leer () {
            SQLiteDatabase sql = getReadableDatabase();
            return sql.query(AlumnosColumnas.TABLE_NAME, null, null, null, null, null, null);
        }

    }

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        EditText nombre, apellido, edad, dni;
        SQLiteHelper sql;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            nombre = findViewById(R.id.nombre);
            apellido = findViewById(R.id.apellido);
            edad = findViewById(R.id.edad);
            dni = findViewById(R.id.dni);

            sql = new SQLiteHelper(getApplicationContext());
        }

        public void enviar(View view) {
            Alumno a = new Alumno (nombre.getText().toString(), apellido.getText().toString(), dni.getText().toString(), Integer.valueOf( edad.getText().toString()));
            sql.añadirAlumno(a);
        }
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

es bastante sencillo, así es como yo crearia el cursor, adaptado a lo que necesitas

```
public class CursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

    public CursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor c) {
        super(context, c,0);
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        return LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        TextView nombre = view.findViewById(R.id.nombre);
        TextView apellido = view.findViewById(R.id.apellido);
        TextView edad = view.findViewById(R.id.edad);
        TextView dni = view.findViewById(R.id.dni);

        nombre.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(AlumnosColumnas.NOMBRE)));
        apellido.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(AlumnosColumnas.APELLIDOS)));
        edad.setText(String.valueOf(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(AlumnosColumnas.EDAD))));
        dni.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(AlumnosColumnas.DNI)));
    }
}
```

También te dejo un ejemplo de como utilizarlo para leer los datos de la base de datos

```
listView = findViewById(R.id.listView2);
sql = new SQLite2AlumnosHelper(getApplicationContext());

Cursor c = sql.leer();

CursorAdapter adaptador = new CursorAdapter(getApplicationContext(), c);

listView.setAdapter(adaptador);
```

Espero que te sirva, un saludo

Comment: Muchísimas gracias me salvas la vida, voy a probar que tal. // Perfecto funciona a la perfección gracias por todo.